# Why is this query stuck if there are no waits?

Tags: sql-server, performance, delete

I am working with a vendor's activity logging system. One of the tables has 70+ million records and is constantly increasing at several hundred records per minute.

They have a utility to delete old records from this table, in batches of 500 records. When this utility is run, the deletes seem to get stuck. There is blocking going on, but the lead blocker (86) never seems to finish. There is no current wait for the lead blocking query (according to sp_WhoIsActive), yet it never finishes. What could be going on?

The database is in SIMPLE recovery mode.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the utility shouldn't perform these deletes in parallel? The whole point of breaking them into chunks is to not overwhelm the underlying I/O, and to minimize blocking and waiting...

Comment: There are a couple of things you could check.  Look at dm_os_waiting_tasks to see if there are tasks for spid 86 that are waiting.  The open_tran_count jumps out at me.  It's possible that the DELETEs are wrapped in a explicit transaction that is not being committed or rolled back, although in that case you'd expect it to be sleeping, not suspended.

Comment: @AaronBertrand That does seem to defeat the point of batching, but the utility provides no options other than "GO".

Comment: @SomeGuy well, to be frank, you're just deleting rows. Why do you need a "utility" to do this? http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Comment: @AaronBertrand There are actually many tables, most with constraints, so it's not as simple as a delete query unfortunately.

Comment: Well if the utility is causing problems, you should investigate what statements it is running, and see if that is part of the problem. In any case, once you know what statements it is running, and understand the correct order to perform the deletes, you could run them in your own job without the utility, and correct any of the threading issues the utility doesn't support.

Comment: The first step is to find what types of lock the deletion process (or processes?) are holding. If you have multiple DELETEs running concurrently, they may happen to overlap in the records they are trying to delete.